# XPath in lightning Javascript

Tags: lightning, javascript, component

I have an XPATh expression which i want to use in my lightning javascript file. I tried several examples but i have been unlucky.

Can someone tell me how do i get a reference of the dom using xpath in lightning javascript ?

Comment: Are you trying to create lightning:tree? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:tree/example

Comment: No. What i am trying to do is on load of the detail page, i want to use xpath expression to get the DOM is and then have a window.settimeout to simulate onclick function.

Comment: You can use xpath, but remember it will be filtered through Locker Service... you might not have access.

Comment: Ah thats a bummer. What i want to do SFDCFox is grab the lightning primitive icon dom id so that i can submit a click event. 

Can you please provide me lightning code which takes the xpath as an argument ? I tried with jquery('XPATH_EXPRESSion'), it does not work.

Comment: I want to open the record PATH page as an inline edit. I searched in SFDC but could not find any reference to it.   Is this even possible ?